SavedStateHandle get null with koin
I have SavedStateHandle within ShareViewModel,
and in HomeFragment  get the ShareViewModel from MainActivity,
also pass the ShareViewModel to HomeViewModel,
the problem is get null from SavedStateHandle after app relaunch from background
In the Modules:
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { ShareViewModel(get()) }
    viewModel { (shareViewModel: ShareViewModel) ->
        HomeViewModel(
            shareViewModel
        )
    }
}

class ShareViewModel(
    val stateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel(), KoinComponent {
 val sharedResp: MutableLiveData<Resp?> = stateHandle.getLiveData(KEY_RESP, null)

   fun getSharedResp(): Resp? {
        return sharedResp.value
    }

   fun updateResp(resp: Resp) {
        sharedResp.value = resp
    }
}


class MainActivity : BaseActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {
    private val shareViewModel: ShareViewModel by viewModel()
}

  class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>() {

    private val shareViewModel: ShareViewModel by activityViewModel()
    private val viewModel by viewModel<HomeViewModel> {
        parametersOf(shareViewModel)
    }

class HomeViewModel(
    private val shareViewModel: ShareViewModel,
) 

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Mobile open "Don't keep activities" toggle and run the app
put app into background
relaunch the app
the SavedStateHandle get null, but keep doing this circle about 3 times the SavedStateHandle get value back

Koin module and version:
koin-core:3.4.3
lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.5.1

I had a similiar issue as my viewmodel was not getting the value from savedstate handle via DI through koin, although I am using compose but this was what I did.

modified koin version in my libs.toml (from
#koinAndroid = "3.2.0-beta-1" to koinAndroid = "3.4.0") [libraries] koin-android = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-android",version.ref = "koinAndroid" }
koin-androidx-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose", version.ref = "koinAndroid" }
koin-androidx-navigation = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-navigation", version.ref = "koinAndroid" }
koin-test-junit4 = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-test-junit4", version.ref = "koinAndroid" }

modified my appmodule to be injected this way
// app module
val appModule = module {
// Provide the WriteViewModel with SavedStateHandle
viewModel { (handle: SavedStateHandle) ->
    WriteViewModel(
        savedStateHandle = handle,
        imageToUploadDao = get(),
        imageToDeleteDao = get()
    )
}

//this didnt work    viewModel { WriteViewModel(get(), get(), get()) }
}

modified how i call my viewmodel via:
//  change from this
//      val viewModel = getStateViewModel()
// to this
val viewModel: WriteViewModel = koinViewModel()
// Get WriteViewModel from Koin


I tested this solution on version 3.4.3 and 3.3.0 of koin and it works. Hope this helps
